# Send data from serial port to a local websever

Tags: arduino

I have a Temp sensor connected to my arduino uno sending its data to the serial monitor e.g

16c

How can I send the data from the serial monitor to a local webserver so that i could access the temp from a internet browser?

Answer (score 0):

In the setup I use with my arduino I am using NodeJS SerialPort module to listen to signals of my arduino with a motion sensor. To serve the signal data to the web in real time, I use the socket.io module for NodeJS. You can find quite a lot about this on the internet, for example this tutorial which is somewhat close to what I use.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389676/Arduino-and-the-Web-using-NodeJS-and-SerialPort